# Kubuntu 18.10: Alfa AWUS036ACH Finding No Networks and Not Connecting

Tags: networking, drivers, kubuntu, network-manager, alfa-wireless

**Solution:** In this case, the lack of functionality seems to have been because of a poor driver version (that I couldn't get to unload from the kernel).  After upgrading to the 4.19 kernel, I installed the [aircrack-ng](https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au/tree/v5.2.20) drivers via the install script and this appears to have resulted in a stable wifi connection.

However, the connection will still drop if the connection details are, e.g., inspected in network-manager.

**Original Problem:** After installing the basic drivers, I got connected to the WiFi. About an hour later, it disconnected and showed no networks in range at all--I tried rebooting, disconnecting the USB, scanning again, etc. Eventually it seemed to start working again.

But then it disconnected and once again shows no networks found.

I've tried looking in Network Manager--every time it connects to a network it seems to make that a new connection restricted to a particular address, and then won't even show the network whilst it's there. On top of disconnecting, now it seems to refuse to connect--it asks for the password once, then, when it would previously go through configuring interface... it does nothing.

lsusb output:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c07e Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1b1c:1b15 Corsair 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 0bda:8812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8812AU 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WLAN Adapter
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 04e8:6863 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9500 [Galaxy S4] / GT-I9250 [Galaxy Nexus] (network tethering)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

iwconfig:

```
      wlx00c0caa60a16  unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
      Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
      Sensitivity:0/0  
      Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

ip link:

```
8: wlx00c0caa60a16: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:c0:ca:a6:0a:16 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Wireless info report: https://pastebin.com/0RHiMV1Z

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `dmesg | grep -e rtl -e wlx` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: That doesn't return anything at all.

Comment: We'll have to dig much deeper. Please provide the wireless info report from here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180

Comment: Wireless info report added.

Comment: Solution added.